# How to program a small program?

Tags: delphi, filesize

I would like to program productive and keep my FileSize very small.
However I would like to know a few tips how do accomplish that.

For example what is better for a small FileSize:

Either:

```
if .... = '1' then begin
 ...
end;
```

or:

```
if ..... = inttostr(1) then begin
...
end;
```

or:

```
if .... = inttostr($0001) then begin
...
end;
```

or:

```
case of intvar
  1: ...
  2: ...
end;
```

Then there is something that I tried and I was surprised.
I made another Unit in my project that stores Strings as constants and then I use the constant vars to replace the strings in my project. For some reason this raises my FileSize although I replace double used Strings as a var now.

Also is it better to store stuff in vars than put them directly into the code?! 
For example:

```
Function1(param1, param2, param3); // this code is used about 20 times in my project
```

or is it better if I:

```
Avar = Function1 (param1,param2,param3); // Store this once in a var and then replace it
```

And what about:

```
if ... = TRUE
```

or:

```
if ....
```

Same as:

```
if .... = FALSE
```

or:

```
if not(...)...
```

Any other tips to program productive for a smaller FileSize?

Thanks in advance.

I use Delphi7

Comment: The things you talk mainly about will have no or completely negligible effect on the EXE size.

Comment: If you want REALLY small exe's you must not use the VCL. It's simple as that. All the optimizations you mention are already handled by the compiler.

Comment: Most of the time productive programming and file size are not related. You should concentrate more on readability and maintainability of your code.

Comment: Why does file size matter to you? It's not as if the entire executable file is going to be loaded. And if you ever had a valid reason for reducing file size, then you should stop using Delphi. It produces very large executables.

Comment: but why does the filesize go up when I put my strings in constant vars? :/

Comment: I doubt that the file size really does go up if you do that.

Comment: You should provide more info - if that is a very simple console application, full source code. Otherwise the question makes little sense.

Comment: If you are using the VCL, as others have said, then any gains you might make by doing this stuff manually will not be very noticeable.  The compiler optimizes the code for you already.  Are you really looking for a small EXE or are you more interested in memory usage?  There are some free tools you can use to compress your EXE such as UPX (http://sourceforge.net/projects/upx/).

Comment: I use console. I know UPX but I asked for tips for optimal coding. I can't provide the source. I will try to optimize a little bit. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Benjamin, StackOverflow is designed around "one question/one answer" per post. You have considerably more questions than that, and therefore your post is inappropriate for SO. (Multiple questions means that several people could each answer a single one, and choosing a correct one would be impossible.) This is specifically mentioned in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) as not being a good fit with the SO format. It's also a discussion type question, which is also inappropriate here. Thanks. :)

Comment: UPX makes things worse in fact. Instead of the loader only loading that part of the executable that you need, it is all loaded. Instead of multiple processes running from a common executable, sharing the same RAM, each process needs its own copy of the unpacked executable.

Comment: do you have 2 GB hdd and 512 Mb RAM on the machine? if not, what are trying to do? re-invent the wheel? is this effort helping the project? if you earn 1 kb on the exe file with 2 weeks of code-writing, you can say that it's worth?

Comment: @RBA I don't think he knows the metrics of how much effort he will need, and how much this will affect the soft. I mean, OP **is** asking how this or that will affect the code. Also, even if I took (insert exaggerated number of) weeks to make [the product](http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=1221), IMHO, it could be worth.

Comment: KOL - Key Objects Library and MCK - Mirror Classes Kit could help you here if you want a really small size without the VCL, around 11k uncompressed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm sorry to be blunt, but you are putting the cart before the horse.

If you really want to know how to make your executable smaller without already knowing what differences will result from your code variations in your given examples, you should just stop right now and read/learn/practice until you know more about the language and the compiler.

Then you'll understand that your question makes little sense per se, as you can already see by all the pertinent comments you got.

- the exact same source code can result in vastly different executables and different source code can result in the same executable, depending on the compiler options/optimizations
- if your main goal is to micro-manage/control the generated exe, program directly in assembler.
- if you want to know what is generated by the compiler, learn how to use the CPU View.
- program for correctness first, then readability/maintainability
- only then, if needed (implies using correct metrics/tools), you can optimize for speed, memory usage or file size (probably the least useful/needed)

Answer (score 4):

Long time ago, i tried to make a program as small as possible, because it had to fit onto a floppy disk (yes i know i'm a dinosaur). This Splitter tool was written in Delphi and is about 50KB in size.

To get it this small, it was necessary to do without a lot of Delphi's units (especially the `Forms` unit and all units with references to it). The only way, was to use the Windows-API directly for the GUI, and i can't think of a reason to do this nowadays, but out of interest.

As soon as you use the VCL, the exe size will grow much more, than all micro optimizations in your code together can reduce it.